# Cannot unmarshal simple Date

Tags: go, arguments, parameter-passing, marshalling

I am starting A tour of Go, but I am experimenting on the way.

I wrote a piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    actualTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(actualTime)
    var marshalledtime []byte
    marshalledtime,_ := actualTime.MarshalJSON()
    fmt.Println(marshalledtime)
    actualTime := (*time.Time).UnmarshalJSON(marshalledtime)
    fmt.Println(actualTime)
}
```

I just wanted to marshal a simple date, and then unmarshal it to just see the process.

But I am completely overhelmed with problems. Up to today GO seemed to be so simple and logical, but now... I don't know, I am stuck.

```
./compile219.go:27:13: cannot use time.(*Time).UnmarshalJSON(marshalledtime) (type error) as type time.Time in assignment
./compile219.go:27:42: not enough arguments in call to method expression time.(*Time).UnmarshalJSON
 have ([]byte)
want (*time.Time, []byte)
```

Why does the last error mean? The documentation clearly says that `UnmarshalJson` takes only one argument, `byte[]`.

What is with the type conversion error?

Comment: You discovered [Method Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) by accident, because you're not calling the method as usual: `actualTime.UnmarshalJSON(b)`. Method expressions are very rarely used in Go, so if that confuses you can safely ignore them for the time being and just take away that you haven't used actualTime anywhere in the method call.

Answer (score 1):

`actualTime.MarshalJSON()` is a method call, it calls the [`Time.MarshalJSON()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.MarshalJSON) method. It returns you the bytes of the JSON representation of the time. Since the bytes printed are not well readable, you should print the byte slice as a string, e.g.:

```
fmt.Println("Raw:", marshalledtime)
fmt.Println("String:", string(marshalledtime))
```

Which outputs:

```
Raw: [34 50 48 48 57 45 49 49 45 49 48 84 50 51 58 48 48 58 48 48 90 34]
String: "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"
```

[`UnmarshalJSON()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnmarshalJSON) is also a method of `time.Time`, so you need a `time.Time` value to call it "on", for example:

```
var time2 time.Time
time2.UnmarshalJSON(marshalledtime)
```

(To be precise, `UnmarshalJSON()` requires a pointer of type `*time.Time` because it has to modify the `time.Time` value, but the Go compiler will rewrite `time2.UnmarshalJSON()` to take `time2`'s address: `(&time2).UnmarshalJSON()`).

`MarshalJSON()` and `UnmarshalJSON()` also return an error which you should always check, for example:

```
var marshalledtime []byte
var err error
marshalledtime, err = actualTime.MarshalJSON()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

And:

```
var time2 time.Time
err = time2.UnmarshalJSON(marshalledtime)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Try the fixed code on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KjoXYRcfpzU).

Also note that it's rare that someone calls `Time.MarshalJSON()` and `Time.UnmarshalJSON()` "by hand". They are to implement the [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interfaces, so when you marshal / unmarshal time values, the `encoding/json` package will call these methods to do the JSON conversion.

This is how the same can be achieved using the `encoding/json` package (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Yq-WKD6csyB)):

Marshaling:

```
var marshalledtime []byte
var err error
marshalledtime, err = json.Marshal(actualTime)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Unmarshaling:

```
var time2 time.Time
err = json.Unmarshal(marshalledtime, &time2)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Although it's not simpler or shorter in this case, the `encoding/json` package is capable of marshaling / unmarshaling arbitrary complex data structures, not just simple time values.

Answer (score 0):

> The documentation clearly says that UnmarshalJson takes only one argument, byte[]

`UnmarshalJson` is the method in case you want to redefine the behavior of `Unmarshal` on a struct. That's not the case here. You don't have to use it unless you want to customize `Unmarshal`. Then UnmarshalJson will be called under the hood when you will make a call to `Unmarshal`

By the way, if you see the signature of `UnmarshalJson` you will see that it does return only an error.

Here is a fix using [json.Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    actualTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(actualTime)
    var marshalledtime []byte
    marshalledtime,_ = actualTime.MarshalJSON()
    fmt.Println(marshalledtime)
    json.Unmarshal(marshalledtime, &actualTime)
    fmt.Println(actualTime)
}
```